# Adobe Acrobat 8 doesn't always show text or images in secured PDF documents

Tags: security, adobe, acrobat

Sometimes when I secure a PDF document in Adobe Acrobat (9), other people using Adobe Acrobat 8 don't see text or images in that new document.
It's consistent on certain documents too.  The only solution I have at the moment is to print a PDF of the document and then secure that version of the document.  That seems to bypass the issue.  But I have 5000 documents I'm batch processing and I'd rather not have to mess with such things.

Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Extra detail.  It looks fine in Acrobat 9 when I open it.

128-bit RC4
Encrypt all document contents
DONT require a password to open the document
DO restrict editing and printing of the document...
<password>
Printing Allowed at High resolution
NO Changes Allowed
DO Enable copying of text, images, and other content.
DO Enable text access for screen reader devices...

Comment: can you provide a sample file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install Acrobat Pro 9 on all our users machines.  Reader 9 is fine too.

HOWEVER, this only fixes it for viewing the PDF on our own machines.  If someone else were to view that file in Acrobat 8, then they would see a blank pdf.

Our solution was to not bother with securing the document.  It causes more trouble than it's worth and apparently it's pretty easy for people to break the security of it.

Answer (score 0):

What type of security are you using? RC4, AES? What options are enabled/disabled? Do you need a password to open the PDF or just modify it?

Comment: Extra detail.  It looks fine in Acrobat 9 when I open it.

128-bit RC4.  
Encrypt all document contents.  
DONT require a password to open the document.  
DO restrict editing and printing of the document...
<password>.  
Printing Allowed at High resolution.  
NO Changes Allowed.  
DO Enable copying of text, images, and other content.  
DO Enable text access for screen reader devices...